# how to break line after certain length using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I break the line after typing for certain length in javascript. In my application, the line must break after it reaches the length 10. I have the following code:

```
<script>
function breakLine()
{
    var l = document.getElementById("textarea1").value;
    if(l.length > 10)
    {
        l = l + "<br />";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="textarea1" onKeyUp="breakLine()" rows="5" cols="100"></textarea>
</body>
```

Comment: Hint : iterate over the string using a for loop and insert a break tag every time the index is divisible by 10 (i%10==0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `\n` for forcing a new line.

Currently you are simply modifying the string. You are not assigning the modified string back to the text area.

check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/xbm2d/)

```
function breakLine()
{
    var l = document.getElementById("textarea1").value;
    if(l.length % 10 == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("textarea1").value = l + "\n";
    }
}
```

*update:*
the following should slightly reduce DOM accessing by keeping an activeNode refference

```
function breakLine()
{
  var txt = document.getElementById("textarea1");
  if(txt.value.length % 10 == 0)
   {
     txt.value = txt.value + "\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try your own fiddle? As soon as you go over 10 chars it add a line break after every char!

Comment: @Jamiec sorry that was an old version of fiddle, set the correct one as base now..  thanks for pointing out:)

Answer (score 1):

I think something like that can help to you:

```
<textarea name="" id="t" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

JS

```
$("#t").on("keydown", function(e){
  var vl = $(this).val();
  if(vl.length % 10 == 0) {
    $(this).val(vl + "\n");
  }
});
```

Play with [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/23zGS/1/)

Comment: Breaks the delete/backspace key at the end of a line